# How to draw High-Precision-Numbers in chartjs

Tags: javascript, chart.js

The number precision of my data is about 0.000001,

let's take some demo value between 0.01 and 0.02,

such as

```
[0.010001
,0.011111
,0.012222
,0.013333
,0.014444
,0.015555
,0.016666
,0.017777
,0.018888
,0.019999
];
```

when I plot with these datasets,
and then hover to any points,
all of them tooltips with precision of only 0.001,
looks like all value has run with (original-data).toFixed(3),

but I want to show the real original value,
or more precision like 0.000001

Is there any way to set float precision in chartjs?

Comment: https://www.avioconsulting.com/blog/overcoming-javascript-numeric-precision-issues   go through it, I think it will solve your problem.

Comment: Hello, my question is about the behavior of library chartjs,
you insert high precision numbers,
but chartjs always output value with ().toFixed(3) ....
--
Not about the calculation error of float number in javascript.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can adjust the label callback so you can return the raw value instead of the parsed value of chart.js like so:

```js
const options = {
  type: 'line',
  data: {
    labels: ["Red", "Blue", "Yellow", "Green", "Purple", "Orange", "Yellow", "Green", "Purple", "Orange"],
    datasets: [{
      label: '# of Votes',
      data: [0.010005, 0.011111, 0.012222, 0.013333, 0.014444, 0.015555, 0.016666, 0.017777, 0.019888, 0.019999],
      borderColor: 'pink'
    }]
  },
  options: {
    plugins: {
      tooltip: {
        callbacks: {
          label: (ctx) => (`${ctx.dataset.label}: ${ctx.raw}`)
        }
      }
    }
  }
}

const ctx = document.getElementById('chartJSContainer').getContext('2d');
new Chart(ctx, options);
```

```html
<body>
  <canvas id="chartJSContainer" width="600" height="400"></canvas>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/3.7.0/chart.js"></script>
</body>
```